# Detecting type of data in c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14

Here's the c++ code printing out the buf array, filled with 0, 1, 2, ... 254

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
        int buf[255];

        auto it_b = std::begin(buf);
        auto it_e = std::end(buf);

        std::iota(it_b, it_e, 0);
        std::copy(it_b, it_e, std::ostream_iterator<decltype(*it_b)>(std::cout, " "));

        std::cout << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

I tried to make it generic so there's only one place where the type is explicilty given `int`

As I need to explicilty declare the type for `ostream_iterator` I wonder what is the best way to achieve this.

1. `decltype(*it_b)`
2. `decltype(buf[0])`
3. something other ...

What are the pros/cons of using this or that method?

For this time assume that we are stuck with C-style arrays.

Comment: `std::decay_t<declval(..)>` to avoid references.

Comment: `using type = int;`, and using `type` after ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be rigorously correct, you should use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits):

```
std::copy(it_b, it_e, std::ostream_iterator<
    typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(it_b)>::value_type
>(std::cout, " "));
```

One problem with `decltype(*it_b)` alone is that it will return a reference in most cases, and that would mess with the outer template that you're instantiating. You could remove the reference by hand, too:

```
std::copy(it_b, it_e, std::ostream_iterator<
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*it_b)>
>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Why not `decay_t`? That would also remove any cv qualifiers, which we do not want here, I guess.

Comment: @leemes it depends. `std::decay_t` emulates passing its parameter to a function so it does quite a lot of stuff that may or may not be relevant. The most robust option remains `iterator_traits`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably neither of those are what you want - in both cases you're ending up with an lvalue reference to your type, in this case `int&`. You could avoid it by using `std::decay`, i.e.

```
std::copy(it_b, it_e, std::ostream_iterator<std::decay_t<decltype(*it_b)>>(std::cout, " "));
```

The easiest thing to do is to keep the type aliased and use that alias:

```
using type = int;
type buf[255];

auto it_b = std::begin(buf);
auto it_e = std::end(buf);

std::iota(it_b, it_e, 0);
std::copy(it_b, it_e, std::ostream_iterator<type>(std::cout, " "));

std::cout << std::endl;
```

This will also work with pathological containers like `vector<bool>`, where deducing the type may lead to surprising (and undefined) behavior.

Comment: In what way is a `vector<bool>` a container?  ;)

Comment: I knew stretching the truth would bite me ;) In all honesty, though, `vector<bool>` is a part of *[containers]* and does fulfil most of the requirements.